# i am trying to fetch top performing city in django through foreign key - Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-templates

here i am trying to fetch top performing city from sql where they are connected through forienkey.

Models

```
class Orders(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers , on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING  , blank = True  , null = True)
  product = models.ForeignKey('Products' , on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING )

class Customers(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length =100 , blank=True)
  date_created_gmt = models.DateField(blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50 ,blank=True)
```

so basically orders table have multiple orders with product_id and customer_id as foriegnkey. customer table have each customers address with city , pincode etc.

so from this i need top performing city. city names which have highest orders in descending order.
your help will appriciate. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In-order to get the count of customers who placed order with respect to city, you can make use of annotate.

```
Orders.objects.values('customer__city').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('-count')
```

1. values('customer__city') -> get the queryset containing dictionary with 'customer__city' as key and corresponding city name as value.
2. annotate('count'=Count('id')) -> creates 'count' key for every object and number of occurences of city name will be the corresponding value.
3. order_by('-count') -> sorts the entire queryset in descending order of 'count', that provides city with highest orders.